# Setting CSS styles with destructured JS object

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create an object with the styles that I need and then set them to my element simply by destructuring and combining the objects, but for whatever reason it is not working:

```
const styles = { color: "#FFFFFF" }

const element = document.querySelector(".someElementSelector");

element.style = { ...element.style, ...styles };
```

However the styles just get set to empty strings, I know that because if I do:

```
const styles = { color: "#FFFFFF" }

const element = document.querySelector(".someElementSelector");

element.style.color = "#FFFFFF";

element.style = { ...element.style, ...styles };
```

`color` is an empty string "", but if I remove the last line with destructuring entirely, the color is being set correctly.

Comment: @MisterJojo can you explain how they are different, when the property names are the same?

Comment: Again, I dont see how that answers my question, I am destructuring its own styles first, so that all of it is in there, and then destructuring my own styles on top of it, which should only overwrite the styles that I have in my object, I dont see how the complexity is related to this? Apparently it is doing something, because it IS overwriting the styles that I want, the problem is that its simply setting them to empty strings, none of the other styles from the complex object are lost.

Comment: destructuring method doesn't accept objects with functions and prototype, or simply multi levels objects

Comment: That is the first time I have ever had issue with destructuring, no matter if there are functions or multi levels, anyway, probably you are right about it and I am missing something.

Comment: DOM elements are not JS objects, they are designed to meet graphical needs and must comply with XML standards, they are 2 very different object worlds.

Comment: That makes sense now, thanks :)

Comment: My answer clear answers your questions, and suggests alternative. Why are you not providing any feedback/reaction?

Comment: @connexo it almost does, for some properties it is not working (one such property being `transform`, I am trying to set `transform: rotate(XXdeg)` and I am trying to figure out if I am doing something wrong or whats happening and when I do I will reply with feedback and/or accept it :)

Comment: Rotating works as well, you just need to make sure you don't rotate it out of your viewport using `transform-origin`.

Comment: @connexo by not working, I mean that the style itself is not working at all when applied with Object.assign() I will add a comment to your post tomorrow :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) is a **read-only** object. If you assign a string it automatically instead is assigned to its property `cssText`.

You can destructure using `Object.entries(styles)`:

```js
const styles = {
  color: "red",
  fontSize: "30px",
  textDecoration: "underline",
  transform: "rotate(45deg)",
  transformOrigin: "top left"
}

for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries(styles)) {
  el.style[prop] = value;
}
```

```html
<div id="el">ABC</div>
```

You can also use `Object.assign()` (which basically is a shortcut to the first example):

```js
const styles = {
  color: "red",
  fontSize: "30px",
  textDecoration: "underline",
  transform: "rotate(45deg)",
  transformOrigin: "top left"
}

Object.assign(el.style, styles);
```

```html
<div id="el">ABC</div>
```

Comment: This solved my problem exactly the way I needed it to work (I am still debating with myself whether to use the `.assign` or the loop version, since with the loop version I skip using `.style` all the time), whatever issues I had were due to syntax errors in my CSS strings. Works perfectly.